# gcc on raspberry half precision floating point (binary16, alternative, __fp16) uses library function

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm, precision, neon

I some machine learning based algorihm on a raspberry pi 3 with huge arrays of stored coefficients, that do not need full float32 precision.

I tried to use half precision floating point for storing this data to reduce the programs memory (and maybe memory bandwidth) footprint.

The rest of the algorithm stays the same.

Comparing the float32 with the float16 version i got a (significant: + 33% runtime of my test program) performance loss when using `__fp16`, although the conversion should be supported by the cpu.

I took a look into the asembler output and also created a sinple function that just reads a `__fp16` value and returns a it as `float` and it seems that some library function call is used for the the conversion. (the same function is called than in the actual code)

The rapspberry's cpu should have half precision hardware support, so I expected to see some instruction loading the data and to not see any performance-impact (or see improvement due to reduced memory bandwidth requiremenents)

I am using the following compiler-flags:

```
-O3 -mfp16-format=alternative -mfpu=neon-fp16 -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon
```

here the small piece of code and the assembler outputs for the little test function:

```
const float test(const Coeff *i_data, int i ){
  return (float)(i_data[i]);
}
```

using `float` for `Coeff`:

```
    .align  2
    .global test
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu neon
    .type   test, %function
test:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    add r1, r0, r1, lsl #2  @ tmp118, i_data, i,
    vldr.32 s0, [r1]    @, *_5
    bx  lr  @
```

using `__fp16` for `Coeff` (`-mfp16-format=alternative`):

```
    .align  2
    .global test
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu neon
    .type   test, %function
test:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    lsl r1, r1, #1  @ tmp118, i,
    push    {r4, lr}    @
    ldrh    r0, [r0, r1]    @ __fp16    @, *_5
    bl  __gnu_h2f_alternative   @
    vmov    s0, r0  @,
    pop {r4, pc}    @
```

using `__fp16` for `Coeff` (`-mfp16-format=ieee`):

```
    .align  2
    .global test
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu neon
    .type   test, %function
test:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    lsl r1, r1, #1  @ tmp118, i,
    push    {r4, lr}    @
    ldrh    r0, [r0, r1]    @ __fp16    @, *_5
    bl  __gnu_h2f_ieee  @
    vmov    s0, r0  @,
    pop {r4, pc}    @
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Are there any authoritative specifications for the A53 processor used by the Rasperry Pi 3 that state that it includes hardware support for FP16? All I can find with a quick search is that FP16 support is an *optional* feature of ARMv8.2 processors.

Comment: A quick perusal of the [ARM-specific gcc options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) suggests different flags than are used here to turn on FP16: `-march=armv8.2-a+fp16`

Comment: @njuffa yes it has an `vfpv4` fpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler flag `-mfpu=neon` overrides the earlier `-mfpu=neon-fp16` since `-mfpu=` can only be specified once.

It was a mistake that it was set twice (it was added in a different place in the Makefile).

But since the raspberry 3 has a vfpv4 that always has fp16 support, the best specification is `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4`.

In this case no library calls are generated by the compiler for the conversion.

edit: according to this [ghist](https://gist.github.com/fm4dd/c663217935dc17f0fc73c9c81b0aa845)
`-mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -mneon-for-64bits` can be used for Raspberry 3.

Answer (score 1):

On ARM's site: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0774d/chr1421838476257.html

Note
The __fp16 type is a storage format only. For purposes of arithmetic and other operations, __fp16 values in C or C++ expressions are automatically promoted to float.

Comment: yes that is clear and this is that i intend: i thought that this is clear from my question - i rephrased it a bit. The question is, that I may have missed, and why the gcc does use the library function for this conversion